# Java/Typescript | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetY') kendogrid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with my datasource. Everything is fine: The rows are correct, my datas are displayed correctly. Just everything fine.

But when I scroll to the right in the grid (because there are more columns to see) then I get following error in the Browser developer console:

```
global-error-handler.ts:50 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetY')
at RowReorderService.press (progress-kendo-angular-grid.mjs:6202:37)
at GridComponent.handleReorderEvents (progress-kendo-angular-grid.mjs:19760:39)
at GridComponent_ng_container_7_Template_kendo_grid_list_press_2_listener (progress-kendo-angular-grid.mjs:20692:26)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:15712:16)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15745:22)
at platform-browser.mjs:666:17
at platform-browser.mjs:1745:21
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26207:33)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
```

The problem is: everything seems fine, I can scroll to right and the datas and columns are displayed like I implemented...

```
global-error-handler.ts:50 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetY')
at RowReorderService.press (progress-kendo-angular-grid.mjs:6202:37)
at GridComponent.handleReorderEvents (progress-kendo-angular-grid.mjs:19760:39)
at GridComponent_ng_container_7_Template_kendo_grid_list_press_2_listener (progress-kendo-angular-grid.mjs:20692:26)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:15712:16)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15745:22)
at platform-browser.mjs:666:17
at platform-browser.mjs:1745:21
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26207:33)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.